# How can I add new URLS to Django 3.2 under /admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on upgrading an old Django project to 3.2. Previously, our urls.py for the main project included the following so that the urls from [impersonate](https://hg.code.netlandish.com/%7Epetersanchez/django-impersonate) were below /admin

```
url(r"^admin/", include(admin.site.urls))
url(r"^admin/impersonate/", include("impersonate.urls")),
```

When I update this code to django 3.2, I don't seem to be able to include any urls beneath /admin. The following code:

```
re_path(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls),
re_path(r"^admin/impersonate/", include("impersonate.urls")),
```

does not work, but it does work if I modify the impersonate line to:

```
re_path(r"^impersonate/", include("impersonate.urls")),
```

Basically, I want to preserve all of the impersonate urls to be beneath /admin, if this is still possible. I understand that this does not make them require admin permissions, rather this is just to group all the admin views of the project together.

I have seen that I can write a custom [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls) also, but this will still move the urls to under `/admin/myapp/mymodel/my_view/`. I do not want the extra part of the path `mymodel` here.

Comment: Why did you remove the `include(...)` for `admin.site.urls`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem My understanding is this is not needed anymore: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/admin/#hooking-adminsite-instances-into-your-urlconf

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to reorder the paths:

```
re_path(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls),
re_path(r"^admin/impersonate/", include("impersonate.urls")),
```

Answer (score 0):

Any URL patterns you define for custom admin views must occur before the admin patterns.

```py
re_path(r"^admin/impersonate/", include("impersonate.urls"))
re_path(r"^admin/", admin.site.urls),
```